# Why is the collection of zeroes of all derivatives of an analytic function also open?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$

Let $E_n = \{w\in\Omega | f^{(n)} (w) = 0\}$

Let $E = \cap_{n\geq 0} E_n$

Clearly, $E_n$ are closed because they are pre-image of the closed set $\{0\}$ and $f^{(n)}$ are continuous

As $E_n$ are closed, so is $E$

But how can I show that $E$ is also open set ?

Comment: Taylor series at a point $w \in E$ has all coefficients zero, so all the points in a small neighborhood are in $E$

Comment: For $ \bigcup_{n\geq 0} E_n$ then $0$ is an accumulation point with $f(z)= 
 \cos(z) -\sin(2z)$ @Conrad

Comment: @reuns $E$ is the intersection of $E_n$ not the union

Comment: Sure but the intersection is trivial, the union is not

Comment: @reuns - not necessarily if for example, $\Omega$ is not connected as I think that is the thrust of the OP question;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is empty then you're done, so suppose $w \in E$. Then $f$ has a convergent power series expression in some neighborhood $U$ of $w$. By the Cauchy integral formula, the coefficients of this series are $a_n = f^{(n)}(w)/n!$. But all of these derivatives vanish, so the power series is just the constant term $a_0$. This holds on all of $U$, so all of the derivatives of $f$ vanish on $U$. Hence, $U \subseteq E$. As $w \in E$ was arbitrary, $E$ is open.

Comment: $n$ starts at $0$, so you even have $a_0=0$ as well.